# Global URI object missing slash after base url

Tags: url

I tried for an hour, but I can't find the solution.

When my site form or link that missed the forward slash.

Also I found the link below, but there is no solution for the issue.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2302843

Comment: No one know....

Comment: i checked the code, JURI::getInstance() return without slash, how can change override this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any of your code, but there is one thing you need to remember.

When using `JUri::root()` or `JUri::base()` etc, if you use `true`, then the forward slash will be omitted, for example:

```
JUri::root()
```

will return:

> http://example.com/something/

and

```
JUri::root(true)
```

will return:

> something

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the URL before, updated now